# Tengo este Error Code : 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Ocupo arreglar este problema alguna ayuda, el error me da al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado principal.

Procedimiento principal

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbinterfaces`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_InsertarFactura`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_InsertarFactura`(IN FechaPedido DATE,IN SubTotal DECIMAL (12,2),IN Descuento DECIMAL (12,2),IN Total DECIMAL (12,2),IN NumeroLinea FLOAT,IN CodigoProducto VARCHAR(20),IN CantidadPedido DECIMAL (12,2),IN Precio DECIMAL(12,2),IN PorcentajeDescuento SMALLINT(6),IN MontoDescuento DECIMAL (12,2))
BEGIN
DECLARE Codigo FLOAT;
SET Codigo = (SELECT * FROM enc_pedido,det_pedido 
WHERE `det_pedido`.`COPR` = CodigoProducto COLLATE 'latin1_spanish_ci'
GROUP BY enc_pedido.`NUPE`); 
CALL `SP_InsertarDetallePedido` (NumeroLinea,CodigoProducto,CantidadPedido,Precio,PorcentajeDescuent,MontoDescuento);
CALL `SP_AñadirEncabezadoProducto` (Codigo,FechaPedido,SubTotal,Descuento,Total);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Procedimiento de insertarDetallePedido

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbinterfaces`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_InsertarDetallePedido`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_InsertarDetallePedido`(NumeroLinea FLOAT, CodigoProducto VARCHAR(20), CantidadPedido DECIMAL (12,2),Precio DECIMAL(12,2), PorcentajeDescuento SMALLINT(6),MontoDescuento DECIMAL (12,2))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO det_pedido (`NUPE`,`NULI`,`COPR`,`CAPE`,`PRPE`,`PODE`,`MODE`) VALUES ("",NumeroLinea,CodigoProducto,CantidadPedido,Precio,PorcentajeDescuento,MontoDescuento);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Procedimiento para insertarEncabezaProducto

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbinterfaces`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_AñadirEncabezadoProducto`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_AñadirEncabezadoProducto`(CodigoPedido VARCHAR (20),FechaPedido DATE, SubTotal DECIMAL (12,2), Descuento DECIMAL (12,2),Total DECIMAL (12,2))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO enc_pedido (`NUPE`,`FEPE`,`SUPE`,`DEPE`,`TOPE`) VALUES (CodigoPedido,FechaPedido,SubTotal,Descuento,Total);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
SET Codigo = (SELECT * FROM enc_pedido,det_pedido
```

`Codigo` es un valor (una "columna") pero la select va a devolver múltiples columnas (es un `select *` sobre dos tablas) y puede que múltiples filas.

Tienes que cambiar la selección para que sólo devuelva una única columna.